# I can't import requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, byte, valueerror

i cant import requests library and get this error:

```
import requests
  File "C:\Users\Tochka2061\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\Tochka2061\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "C:\Users\Tochka2061\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 33, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

How i can solve it? Ive already tried to delete python and install it again, it didnt help.

Comment: What method are you using to install Python?

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling the library and reinstalling?... Are you using pip?

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @Wilson i installed last version from the official sourse  https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @okayatcp12 I tried pip install requests --upgrade

Comment: @C_Z_ Im using VS code

Comment: Have you tried uninstalled requests and re-installing?

Comment: What is the encoding on your VS code? UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: Try to use **IDE PyCharm** community it auto import and install needed dependencies.

Comment: @C_Z_ No? how i can reinstall? There is UTF-8 in my VS code

Comment: No one noticed that error is: `ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes` it is an issue related to file encoding. Also, as I can see you're using the latest version of Python. Try to install either 3.6 or 3.7 or 3.8

Comment: Try `pip uninstall requests` and then `pip install requests`. UTF-8 is the correct encoding so thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

@Trepetaky I was able to resolve this issue by installing the missing module chardet with `pip install chardet`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).